# Angular/JS Javascript Open IE FIle upload input, opens multiple times if clicked cancel / Open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a simple form with upload button,

the Input type file is hidden and the custom button is clicking on the input in the controller.

The issue is: IE window is open over again and again if i click cancel or Open,

I'm not sure why, if you can share your thoughts it can help:

This is the HTML code:

```
   <li ng-click="upload()">
                        <input id="uploadVideo" type="file" nv-file-select="" uploader="assetsUploader" multiple class="upload-video-hidden">
                        <div class="video-companion-icon big-menu-icon"></div>
                        <p class="menu-text">Video / Companion</p>
                    </li>
```

The controller code, i tried 2 options:

```
 $scope.upload = function () {
            setTimeout(function(){
                angular.element('#uploadVideo').click();

            },100);
        };
```

or

```
$scope.upload = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        angular.element('#uploadVideo').click();
    }, 100);
};
```

They both didn't work.

One thing to mention  i'm using angularFileUpload module.

https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload

But i removed the attributes from the input field an it's still happens,

The IE version is 11.0.9600.187239

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ng-click="upload($event)"
```

And

```
 $scope.upload = function () {
angular.element('#uploadVideo').click();
$event.stopPropogation();
        };
```